# Trying to create a script that counts the length of a all the reads in a fastq file but getting no return

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, fastq

I am trying go count the length of each read in a fastq file from illumina sequencing and outputting this to a tsv or any sort of file so I can then later also look at this and count the number of reads per file. So I need to cycle down the file and eactract each line that has a read on it (every 4th line) then get its length and store this as an output

```sh
num=2
for file in *.fastq
do
    echo "counting $file"
    function file_length(){
    wc -l $file | awk '{print$FNR}'
    }
    for line in $file_length
    do
        awk 'NR==$num' $file | chrlen > ${file}read_length.tsv
        num=$((num + 4))
    done
done
```

Currently all I get the counting $file and no other output but also no errors

Answer (score 1):

Your script contains a lot of errors in both syntax and algorithm. Please try shellcheck to see what is the problem. The most issue will be the `$file_length` part.
You may want to call a function `file_length()` here but it is just
an undefined variable which is evaluated as null in the `for` loop.

If you just want to count the length of the 4th line of `*.fastq` files,
please try something like:

```
for file in *.fastq; do
    awk 'NR==4 {print length}' "$file" > "${file}_length.tsv"
done
```

Or if you want to put the results together in a single tsv file, try:

```
tsvfile="read_lenth.tsv"
for file in *.fastq; do
    echo -n -e "$file\t" >> "$tsvfile"
    awk 'NR==4 {print length}' "$file" >> "$tsvfile"
done
```

Hope this helps.